# Applescript variable type for folders

Tags: applescript

I have a script I wrote (with the help of the internet) long ago that moves a selected file to a folder. This is the code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:dbooster:Desktop:Outbox"
    repeat with x in selected_items
        move x to theFolder

    end repeat

end tell
```

I don't know if this is well written or not, but until yesterday, this worked perfectly, always moving any file I selected to the Outbox folder on my desktop. But now suddenly it throws me an error. I have no idea what changed. I haven't reboot my computer in a few weeks; the script was working fine last night, but then I rebooted my computer early this morning and now the script throws an error.

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t make \"Macintosh HD:Users:dbooster:Desktop:Outbox\" into type folder." number -1700 from "Macintosh HD:Users:dbooster:Desktop:Outbox" to folder

So, uhm... from a non-programmer... what exactly does that error mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: is the folder still there ? just a sanity check on this.However I think that might be the problem

Comment: Also restarting script editor can help... Weird things can happen if you made sure everything is still there. Can also check that the folder has same spelling and caps if it was recreated recently.